# Please help me plug values into an MA(q) model

Tags: excel, moving-average

yt = u + 0et + 0et-1 + 0et-2

01=  .5
02 = .25

My series of existing data is :

1,0,2,0,1,0

So I estimate the first forecast value will be :

yt+ 1 = .66 + .5(-.66) + .25 * .34
yt = 1 = .4125

I have had a go at this in an excel document but I am certain it is not correct.

At this stage I am not estimating the first error term just 
trying to understand how this works by plugging numbers into an existing formula.

I don't understand how 0et would possibly work how can you know the error of something you're trying to forecast ?

I will work on the rest of it as I go along.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59712/the-way-an-maq-model-works

Comment: Hey, thanks I read through that already. I really need an example to see this applied without changes from a stats package otherwise I have no way of knowing if what I'm doing is right.